# Need help on Analytics API - Web Property Name and Account Name (in .Net)

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics

I am downloading Analytics data using the Google Analytics Dot.Net libraries. I am able to get the report data using the AnalyticsService object. It returns Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.GaData. My query consists of dimensions, metrics and profileid (View Id).

I need to know the Account Name and Web Property name, unfortunately returned GaData has webPropertyId and accountid, but not the names.
How do I get the name?

I tried -

```
GaData response = analyticsservice.Execute();
var webproperty = service.Management.Webproperties.Get(response.ProfileInfo.AccountId,response.ProfileInfo.WebPropertyId);
```

but this returned webproperty doesn't have name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about .net, but for other libraries you can use the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) to retrieve Account Name, etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter what Library, you're correct, the Management API is what you want to use to retrieve that information.

Comment: I am kinda new in GA. Are you guys referring to other Management API? In this case, as I showed above I am using service.Management.Webproperties but that didn't help. Also, I am seeing similar example in java - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/list.. but it is not working in .Net.